# What does 相手を見て物をいいなよ mean here?

Tags: translation

> ！
>   ……ハッ！　……
>   フッ、だまされるわけないだろ。
>   相手を見て物をいいなよ。
>   オレはこの道のプロだぜ。

I'm having trouble translating this part - 相手を見て物をいいなよ。

[物を言う](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E7%89%A9%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86.html) has two meanings, so I guess the sentence will be something like -

> **Watch the opponent, then make a conclusion!** or **Watching the opponent is everything!**

Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ものを言う is simply "to speak". 相手 in this case is the person in front of the speaker, the person you're talking to right now. The sentence means "Speak after seeing (checking) who you're talking to," whose implication here is "You've picked the wrong person (to trick)."